# Diffrent date in view and model than in POST

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

So I'm using moment.js to get my local date. And it's working. In the view and in the angular model I have my local time.

But when I'm sending POST to my php script, date is returning to GMT time (checked in request payload).
To be sure, just before the request I'm writing date from the model to the console. And it's my local date!

I'm out of ideas what can be wrong.

Comment: thats the default behavior, i had written directive to remove the zone part from dates so that they stay consistent

Comment: yeah thats it! thank you

Comment: Just as an FYI, it's much better to write server software to use UTC/GMT, especially if you plan to deploy it across multiple countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per comments.. sharing the directive code

```
csapp.directive('csDateToIso', function () {

    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
            return moment(datepickerValue).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

it removes the timezone part from the selected date... though be aware of @jpaugh advice